# How to make cards on the image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make a card, on the image here similarly like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
 <section>
  <div class="download-section">
    <div class="container">
```

```
          <div id="raise" class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.download-section {

        width: 100%;
         color: #fff;
        background: url(../img/projects.jpg) center center no-repeat #000;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
```

I am trying to make a card, but I don't see the table boundary. I am using Bootstrap-3. 
Can someone help me? how can i fix it.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail? or provide a plunker or something?

Comment: @JVLobo i have edited,now check it might help now

Comment: I still don't understand your question and I don't see any snippet or plunker to run and try to help

Comment: @JVLobo i need to make a card, as i had shown you on above image.

Comment: First error... `row` goes before than `col`...

Comment: What is this `card` terminology you speak of?

Comment: @DannyCullen area where you see login, that is what i am calling card

Comment: @anfuca thanks it got fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach of what I think you want... Something like this:

We have a *container*, with a *row* inside it that has 3 *cols*. Total sum must be 12, so we add 3 `col-md-4`.

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel mycard">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Here goes some beautiful text</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel mycard">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Here goes some beautiful text</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel mycard">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Here goes some beautiful text</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.mycard {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create a box,if i create a table it won't be seprated. Can we make a box like,with spacing?

Comment: yes, it is displaying like this,  https://i.gyazo.com/36920bc099104058f0baf24e8338e310.png

Comment: That's the problem,i need to create a box . I am getting tables. See,the image in the question

Comment: Ok, I update my answer... Let's use `panel` instead of `col`